# Access rails active storage objects from sidekiq in different docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, sidekiq, rails-activestorage

we're having a rails 6 app holding files via ActiveStorage. So far, requests dealing with uploading files etc. last some time because we're currently working non-asynchronous. Now we're switching to background processing. Everything related to files specifically is causing headache, because the files reside in one docker container in the realm of our rails service but need to be accessed from a separate sidekiq container where unfortunately ActiveJob tasks are not able to find the ActiveStorage objects (`ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError`).

So - if any - what would be the best approach to make ActiveStorage ressources accessible to sidekiq in a multi-container docker setup?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess if you use the `Disk` service you'll have a hard time exposing those files. If a cloud service (S3, Azure) is not a viable solution, I'd look into a self hosted S3 clone.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use disk service on active storage(I should point out that if you do not store the rails app or the storage directory on the host, then you will lose your files when the container is restarted.). If your files are in disk service, if you want to use them in the background processor, then you can link both the rails app and the app directory in the background processor from your host, or you can link the storage directory to both of them from the host. As an example, you can look at the following article;
https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/dockerize-a-rails-5-postgres-redis-sidekiq-action-cable-app-with-docker-compose

Comment: Thx a lot for the reference, gonna try that one out!